# Display selected options in a text area

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to change the text in the text area using radio buttons for the size of the font and check boxes for the style of the font. I don't know how to display the text in the text area please see the last two lines.

```
package assignment3;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
public class Assignment3 extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
  JPanel panel;
  JTextArea area;
  JRadioButton small;
  JRadioButton medium;
  JRadioButton large;
  ButtonGroup btngrp;
  JCheckBox bold;
  JCheckBox italic;
  JCheckBox underline;
  Font smalla;
  Font med;
  Font la;
  Font b;
  Font i;
  Font u;
  public Assignment3() {
    setTitle("My Work of text");
    setSize(400, 400);
    panel = new JPanel();
    area = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    btngrp = new ButtonGroup();
    btngrp.add(small);
    btngrp.add(medium);
    btngrp.add(large);
    small = new JRadioButton("Small");
    medium = new JRadioButton("Medium");
    large = new JRadioButton("Large");
    bold = new JCheckBox("Bold");
    italic = new JCheckBox("Italic");
    underline = new JCheckBox("Underline");
    smalla = new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    med = new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 15);
    la = new Font("Rockwell", Font.PLAIN, 20);
    b = new Font("Rockwell", Font.BOLD, 12);
    i = new Font("Rockwell", Font.ITALIC, 15);
    u = new Font("Rockwell", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 20);
    add(panel);
    panel.add(area);
    panel.add(small);
    panel.add(medium);
    panel.add(large);
    panel.add(bold);
    panel.add(italic);
    panel.add(underline);
    small.addItemListener(this);
    medium.addItemListener(this);
    large.addItemListener(this);
    bold.addItemListener(this);
    underline.addItemListener(this);
    italic.addItemListener(this);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Assignment3().setVisible(true);
  }
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
    int style = 0;
    int size = 12;
    if (small.isSelected()) {
      size = 12; /*area.setFont(smalla);*/
    } else if (medium.isSelected()) {
      size = 14; /*area.setFont(med);*/
    } else if (large.isSelected()) {
      size = 20; /*area.setFont(la);*/
    }
    if (bold.isSelected()) {
      style += Font.BOLD
        /*area.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, style, 
        style))*/
      ;
    }
    if (italic.isSelected()) {
      style += Font.ITALIC /*area.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, style, style))*/ ;
    }
    if (underline.isSelected()) {
      style += Font.CENTER_BASELINE /*area.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, style, style))*/ ;
    }
    area.setFont(new Font(size + style); area.setFont(style + size);
    }
  }
```

Comment: the aim is to change the font style in the text area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look through the [JavaDocs for `Font`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html%23Font(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) you will see...

> style - the style constant for the Font The style argument is an
>   integer bitmask that may be PLAIN, or a bitwise union of BOLD and/or
>   ITALIC (for example, ITALIC or BOLD|ITALIC). If the style argument
>   does not conform to one of the expected integer bitmasks then the
>   style is set to PLAIN.

This means you can't simple "add" style constants together, you need use a bit wise union...

```
int style = 0;
int size = 12;
if (small.isSelected()){size=12;/*area.setFont(smalla);*/}
else if (medium.isSelected()){size=14;/*area.setFont(med);*/}
else if (large.isSelected()){size=20;/*area.setFont(la);*/}
if (bold.isSelected()){ 
    style |=Font.BOLD /*area.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, style,  style))*/;
} 
if (italic.isSelected()){
    style |=Font.ITALIC /area.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, style, style))/;
} 
if (underline.isSelected()){
    style |=Font.CENTER_BASELINE /area.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, style, style))/;
}
```

If you read through the JavaDocs, you would also see that Font requires 3 parameters for its constructor, `name`, `style`, `size`

Which means there's no way that this could work...

```
area.setFont(new Font(size + style);
area.setFont(style+size);
```

Now, you don't need to create new instance of Font, you can use the existing instance and alter it to your requirements

```
area.setFont(area.getFont().deriveFont(style, size));
```

...so the short answer would be, read the JavaDocs when stuck...

Answer (score 0):

To put a text in a JTextArea you can use the append() or the setText() methods:

```
JTextArea myTextArea = new JTextArea();
...
myTextArea.setText("What a happy day"); // replaces everything inside the compenent
...
myTextArea.append(" and i'm gonna enjoy it.\n"); // Append the text at the end
```

Comment: area.append(style+size); is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, but i didnt get what you want. So you have some radio buttons, when you select one, you want it to change the style and the font?

Comment: yes see i want the radio buttons to change the size of the font and the checkboxes to change the style of the font